# What exactly is the "i" in iPad, iPhone, iMac etc. linguistically speaking?

Tags: terminology, morphology, affixes

You might ask now:

> *What does the "i" stand for?*

Well, according to the following article
 http://www.iphonejd.com/iphone_jd/2009/01/the-i-in-iphone.html 
the "i" was originally meant to stand for "**internet**", but it was never fixed to the meaning of internet alone; it can also denote other things such as  "**Individual"  "Instruct  "Inform"  "Inspire"**,...

Now, my question is:

> How would be describe the '**i**' in linguistic terms?

1. As some new kind of productive affix?
2. Or would you rather argue *iPad, iPhone* etc. to be compounds, where the first part of the compound was clipped, while the second part of the compound retained its form?
3. Any other good ideas? :)

Comment: I would say this is just silly product naming.

Comment: I'd agree; a form of branding. As to what it is, it's a prefix. Prefixes, like middle initials, don't have to stand for anything.

Comment: Well both *i-* and *e-* took on little lives of their own some time ago. *i-* predates the *iPhone*, going back to the *iMac*. At about that time many products or companies appeared with an *e-* prefix as well. I think Apple defended their *i-* trademark so you don't really see it for non-Apple things officially, but both are used colloquially or in jest. They do seem to be "alive" with a limited degree of productivity as affixes, but they've possibly not proved themselves enough to make it into a "real" dictionary. (Wiktionary might have entries.)

Comment: [Wiktionary entry for *-i*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/i-#Etymology_4).
[Wiktionary entry for *-e*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e-#Etymology_2).

Comment: The *e-* started as an abbreviation for *electronic* so it could be argued that "e-mail" or "e-solutions" are compound words. However, my personal experience is that *e-* is no longer parsed as such and has evolved into something else (most notably the fact that people increasingly are dropping the hyphen).

Comment: It's a lame form of branding. Linguistically, it is no different from Google Chrome, Google Maps, Microsoft Windows, Microsoft Word, Adobe Acrobat, etc. Lame because they can't really trademark just one letter -- but that's not linguistically relevant.

Comment: Goodness gracious! I wrote the Wiktionary links as suffixes instead of prefixes...

Comment: I have heard the (probably apocryphal) story that the _i_ stands for the name of Jonathan Ive, who designed the iMac.

Comment: Both i and e- have the stress of compounds rather than prefixes.  So I vote for compound.

Comment: @GregLee By that logic, *prefix* and *preorder* are compounds, no?

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer, Yes.  Also "pro-" and "amino-" words.

Comment: And *interest* and *telephone*?  And what about https://jakubmarian.com/english-words-that-change-meaning-depending-on-the-stress-position/?  Obviously dictionaries disagree with you on this, and it fails the test of being a valid standalone word, but I'm open to it, if you can explain more.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call this thing a [prefixoid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefixoid), i.e., an element with some but not all features of a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a standard prefix playing on the homophony with "high" and the acronym formations with **i**nternet/**i**nformation. It modifies its base in a way similar to a diminutive, creating an hyponym with connotation. Here, probably, an approbative effect.

To be a compound, it would need a definite base for **i** which seems quite elusive.